# Excel Connector, "An internal server error has occurred while processing your request", and ID column

Tags: api, data-loader, fields, excel, office-connect

I consider myself an expert with Excel Connector.  Therefore, I'm perplexed why I cannot figure this out.  I think it's a known issue that I'm just not finding posted anywhere.  I literally have over 80 routines I run approximately every 15-45 minutes ALL DAY from Excel C Connector.   >:-(

Custom Object:  **Webinar Attendance**

I have a list of IDs from that object in Excel.  I am trying to query fields (narrowed it down to JUST ONE for testing purposes).

**I cannot figure out why it won't work.**  I am unclear if it's the "ID" name I'm using (I've tried

- Webinar Attendance ID
- ID
- Webinar_Attendance_ID
- Webinar_AttendanceID

and many others - the FIRST one being the LOGICAL one).

Any clues?  All I get is "An internal server error has occurred while processing your request".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered and verified the answer.

First line:  **Object name** (underscored API name) - cannot use "friendly name"

Second line:  **Id**

So in my example in my question:

```
Webinar_Attendance__c
Id
```